# Relative Path for SSRS Image File Parameter

Tags: image, ssrs-2008, parameter-passing, relative-path

I am trying to send an image file path as a parameter in ssrs

When I send parameter as

`File:C:\Reports\Images\Banner.jpg`

it works, the image shows up

But when I try to use a relative path like

`File:..\Images\Banner.jpg`

The image does not show up and I get this error

```
rsInvalidImageReference
```

When my rdl gets deployed, the image folder will be in the same directory as the rdl.

Can someone help me pelase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the *Image* folder is just a subfolder on the Report Server, you can pass a string parameter like the following to the report:

```
.\Images\Banner.jpg
```

This assumes you have an image in the report similar to:

[image]

i.e. the **Value** property expression is based on a parameter.